# "Got unknown error from server ..." using Socket.io on Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sockets, socket.io

I'm trying to connect to my Xcode Server's internal socket.io. I initialize the client using this:

```
self.socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: NSURL(string: "https://37.203.216.82")!, options: [.Path("/xcode/internal/socket.io"), .Log(true), .Reconnects(true), .ForceNew(true), .SessionDelegate(self), .SelfSigned(true)])
```

But when I use `self.socket.connect()` I get this response:

```
2016-07-15 16:13:49.179 MyApp[84260:1941316] LOG SocketIOClient: Adding handler for event: connect
2016-07-15 16:13:49.180 MyApp[84260:1941316] LOG SocketIOClient: Adding handler for event: integrationStatus
2016-07-15 16:13:49.180 MyApp[84260:1941316] LOG SocketIOClient: Adding handler for event: advisoryIntegrationStatus
2016-07-15 16:13:49.180 MyApp[84260:1941316] LOG SocketIOClient: Adding engine
2016-07-15 16:13:49.181 MyApp[84260:1941316] LOG SocketEngine: Starting engine. Server: https://37.203.216.82
2016-07-15 16:13:49.181 MyApp[84260:1941316] LOG SocketEngine: Handshaking
2016-07-15 16:13:49.182 MyApp[84260:1941792] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Doing polling request
2016-07-15 16:13:49.317 MyApp[84260:1941792] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Got polling response
2016-07-15 16:13:49.322 MyApp[84260:1941786] LOG SocketEngine: Got message: Welcome to socket.io.
2016-07-15 16:13:49.324 MyApp[84260:1941786] ERROR SocketIOClient: Got unknown error from server Welcome to socket.io.
2016-07-15 16:13:49.326 MyApp[84260:1941786] LOG SocketIOClient: Handling event: error with data: (
"Got unknown error from server Welcome to socket.io."
)
```

I've tried changing the path to the `socket.io.js` file or `xcode/internal/socket.io/1/` but it all gives the same response, instead, `Welcome to socket.io` is replaced by the contents of the file there.

Comment: did u get any solution >?

Comment: Previous minutes still working fine. No library update. Cease to work suddenly.

Answer (score 9):

Socket.IO-Client-Swift (16.0.1): version, need to add: `.forceWebsockets(true)`.

Example:

```
let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "http://localhost:8080")!, config: [.compress, .forceWebsockets(true)])
let socket = manager.defaultSocket
```

https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-swift-fiddle/blob/main/Sources/Fiddle/main.swift

Comment: When I updated my  Socket.IO-Client-Swift to  (16.0.1) I repeatedly got  socket connecting status  so had to revert back to
  pod 'Socket.IO-Client-Swift', '~> 15.2.0'
still I got this issue so I had to add .forceWebsockets(true).
Now its working perfectly .Thanks @ForrestWang

Answer (score 1):

Check socket.io version on both server and client side, mismatch of both may be cause of this error

Answer (score 1):

I have updated swift client framework to the latest `16.0.1` version. But this error happened. There is an open issue also: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift/issues/1355

I have fixed this by reverting to the old stable version:

```
pod 'Socket.IO-Client-Swift', '~> 15.2.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `ws` as the protocol, like this:

```
... NSURL(string: "ws://37.203.216.82") ...
```